# RootSecure using Openvas throws accessible file warnings when redirected to login page

Tags: security, forms-authentication, network-security, openvas

We are using RootSecure to run an Openvas scan of our sites.  However, it continues to say that files like IISADMIN, perl scripts, etc. are found because the site is locked down by forms authentication so any attempt to get to these files gets a 302 to the login page, then a 200 from the login page.  Is there anything we should be doing (beyond moving our  authentication structure) to clear these up, for audit purposes?

Comment: I feel like this is less of an authentication issue and more an authorization one. If these files are not remotely executable without correct authentication, could an attacker who is authenticated but unauthorized run / access them?

Comment: The 404 error redirect does return a 404.  However, because it doesn't get a 404 before getting a 302 to the login page, this handling is rendered moot.  (BTW, none of these files exist much less are accessible, but that "message" can't get across is the issue)

Answer (score 0):

The only VT related to IISADMIN existing in the OpenVAS/Greenbone feed has the OID [1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.10577](https://secinfo.greenbone.net/nvt/1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.10577). This VT has a QoD (Quality of Detection) defined as "remote_banner_unreliable" which means it's detection is unreliable and it doesn't show up on a standard scan of OpenVAS/GVM (because of this unreliability). Could you please check:

1. Which OID are showing such results and is the above mentioned OID included?
2. The filter of your report and if this includes showing results of VTs having a QoD < 70 % (not sure how RootSecure is actually working and is supporting this at all)
3. Which version of OpenVAS/GVM is RootSecure using? Background: there where some bugs in OpenVAS/GVM in the past where VTs with lower QoD got a higher QoD assigned wrongly.
4. If RootSecure is actually using OpenVAS/GVM or just the Greenbone Community Feed?

Based on the answer to 1. above (if the result are coming from that specific OID/VT) there are a few possible solutions (numbers matching the questions above):

2. Update the used report filters to not show results of VTs having a QoD < 70 %
3. Contact RootSecure to get the OpenVAS/GVM installation upgraded to a fixed version
4. Contact RootSecure and ask them to fix their OpenVAS/GVM or feed integration to handle the QoD assigned by that VT correctly

As an alternative switching to a self-hosted/maintained OpenVAS/GVM/GSM solution could be possible as well.

Disclaimer: VT-Dev @ Greenbone